# "Fixed" Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier only to still have my script not work?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, debugging, button

The idea here is simple. You click a button and a link appears. I got the idea after studying this [page](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-append-and-appendto-example/). So I built a prototype. However, I am getting an error which states: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier.

I thought, huh? So I tracked it down to this little guy here:

```
$('#myLink').append('<a href="'http://www.google.com'"><font = "'white'">Googlez</font></a>');
```

Using notepad++, I investigated further and I found the formatting is all messed up. After the url link, it highlighted in green. So this tells me the editor thinks it is text comments. Okay, that's made of fail. So I tried this:

```
$('#myLink').append('<a href="http://www.google.com"><font = "white">Google</font></a>');
```

The editor liked this better. So I went to the browser to test. The error went away. I got the alert message...and then nothing. There is no link after I click my test button. I include the relevant code portions below:

HTML

```
<div id="test">
        <center><input id="generateLink" type="button" value="Test"></center>
    </div>
    <div id="generateResponse">
        <fieldset>
            <center>
            <legend><font color="white">Here is a link</font></legend>
            </center>
                <center>
                    <div id="myLink"></div>
                </center>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

SCRIPT

```
$('#generateLink').click(function(e){
        $('#myLink').html("");
        $('#myLink').append('<a href="http://www.google.com"><font = "white">Google</font></a>');
        alert('I was clicked');
    });
```

My javascript is given above. I attempt to update the div id "myLink". Something like what I found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_xml2), but with the url instead. Given I have no error messages. I have wasted too long figuring out what is wrong. I am thinking about trashing this approach? Ugh. If anyone can spot a quick fix that is alluding my eyes, please feel free to pitch in.

Here is a fiddle example of my entire prototype. A lot of things are suddenly breaking on me now. Please see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/G3KrE/12/). :(

Comment: This works just fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/LwvkL/. Remove the `<font="white">` portion though, that could be doing something funky depending on your browser.

Comment: Is the page doing a postback when you click your button? Try adding `e.preventDefault()` to your click handler.

Comment: I chose white because the background of my page is black.

Comment: I changed background to white and removed font. Still didn't work. Will investigate further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change your single and double quotes as well...this worked fine for me:

```
$('#generateLink').click(function(e){
    $('#myLink').html("");
    $('#myLink').append("<a href='http://www.google.com'><font = 'white'>Google</font></a>");
    alert('I was clicked');
});
```

Comment: It did work fine. I had to remove the button and eventually had the link generate after I was done doing other stuff after the submit. Thanks.I gave rep to all who replied. Thanks for you time all.